# DDD - Composite Aggregate Serialization - design problem

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design, composite, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to apply DDD to one Java project. This is the problem I stumbled upon:

In the domain, I have an Aggregate that is implemented using Composite OOP pattern. Methods on this aggregate produce some domain objects that need to be serialized and sent over the wire. These are options I thought about:

1. In Application Service part of my domain I'm taking aggregate, call it's methods, and try to serialize results to DTO. In order to serialize it to DTO I have to use `instanceof` to check if current node is Composite or Child and continue with serialization. Since `instanceof` is code smell (as I read that it breaks Open/Close principle etc.), I decided to try to use Visitor pattern.
2. In order to apply Visitor pattern, my Composite Aggregate has to implement Visitor which will return DTO's and then DTO's become part of domain layer - which is also not good design (since domain should contain only domain concepts, and DTO's are not part of that). DTO serialization is only technical detail that should not go to domain layer.

Is there any other solution that is not in collision with these design principles?

Is there a way to simulate dynamic binding in java for overloaded methods (other than `instanceof` - since this would solve my problem with option 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Visitor has a generic return type, then the visited classes are not coupled to that type.

```
public interface Node {
    <T> T accept(NodeVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public class ANode implements Node {
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(NodeVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class BNode implements Node {
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(NodeVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public interface NodeVisitor<T> {
    T visit(ANode aNode);
    T visit(BNode bNode);
}

public class DtoNodeVisitor implements NodeVisitor<DTO> {
    @Override
    public DTO visit(ANode aNode) {
        return new DTO(); //use ANode to build this.
    }
    @Override
    public DTO visit(BNode bNode) {
        return new DTO(); //use BNode to build.
    }
}
```

`ANode` and `BNode` have no knowledge of `DTO` here.

Comment: This solution seems OK - for publicly available aggregate state. The only "problem" that I see here is that if I need to serialize internal state of the aggregate (state that should not be accessible from the outside), I would need to implement some Visitor+Memento pattern, and then domain would need to know about DTOs (since DtoNodeVisitor would be part of domain in that case) - but I guess this is inevitable.

Comment: I agree with the Memento assessment; but that shouldn't pull `DtoNodeVisitor` into the domain. The domain can add new (read-only) abstractions around concrete Node states, and `DtoNodeVisitor` can depend on the abstractions rather than the concrete Nodes themselves.

Comment: @jaco0646 what happens when you want to serialize ANode to ADTO and BNode to BDTO - then this solution does not seem to work. And I guess, when you have single DTO, then you actually do not need the generics at all...

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic, logic depending on a concrete type should be implemented in its respective `visit` method.

Answer (score 0):

As first thing, in point 2 I don't get:

> my Composite Aggregate has to implement Visitor

First question coming in my mind is, why?
Can't you declare the visitor as an interface, and pass the implementation as an input parameter of your aggregate?

> Is there a way to simulate dynamic binding in java for overloaded methods (other than instanceof - since this would solve my problem with option 1)?

Yes, you can do it using Reflections, but the real question is, do you want to use them?

I think the answer depends on how many cases you have to manage and how often they change?

If you have a "manageable" number of different cases a solution with the `instanceof` can be a good trade of:

```
public Something myMethod(Entity entity){
    if (entity instanceof AnEntity){
         //do stuffs
    else if (entity instanceof AnotherEntity){
         //do something else
    ...
    else {
         throw new RuntimeException("Not managed " + entity.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Otherwise when maybe you have more cases and want to split the code in their own methods, you can do it using Java `MethodHandle`, let me post an example of usage:

```
package virtualmethods;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class MyObject {

    public String doStuffs(Object i) throws Throwable {
        try {
            final MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(String.class, i.getClass());
            return (String) MethodHandles.lookup()
                .findVirtual(getClass(), "doStuffs", type)
                .invoke(this, i);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not managed " + i.getClass().getName(), e);
        }
    }

    private String doStuffs(Integer i) {
        return "You choose " + i;
    }
    private String doStuffs(Boolean b) {
        return "You choose boolean " + b;
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
package virtualmethods;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        MyObject object = new MyObject();

        System.out.println("Integer => " + object.doStuffs(5));
        System.out.println("Boolean => " + object.doStuffs(true));
        try {
            System.out.println("String => " + object.doStuffs("something"));
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("KABOOM");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The *public* method in `MyObject` taking an `Object` will look for a method named `doStuffs` with a `String` result and an `i.getClass()` as input in class `MyObject` (more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-handles)).
Using this way you can dispatch methods at runtime (using overload is static linking at compile time).
But both methods has the problem that you can't be sure you will manage ALL the types that extends/implements `Entity` in the first case and/or `Object` in the second one, both solutions have an `else` or a `catch` to check when a not managed type is passed to the method.
Be 100% sure you are managing all the types can be only achieved using the solution proposed by @jaco0646, for what I know, it force you to manage all the types, otherwise it won't compile.
Given the amount of boilerplate it needs I would only use when throwing that `RuntimeException` would cause a business problem and I can't assure it is not thrown using proper testing (beside this I found it very fascinating).

Comment: Regarding Visitor implementation - what I meant is that domain will have to know about  DTO, since to serialize internal state of the aggregate that should not be exposed outside, serialization methods must be inside domain (like this class DtoNodeVisitor below). It should have access to aNode.someProtectedMethodToSerializeToDTO().

Comment: The issue of exposing the aggregates internal is that someone can mutate it without having the invariants checked. If you deep copy the internal state of an aggregate and pass to someone else it can't cause any problem to your aggregate.  
If the state is immutable there are no issues to let someone else read it.  
Making the internal state as immutable object, or deep copy it when it is read can let you decouple your layers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are overcomplicating it. If you are needing a `typeof` then your aggregate isn't returning a valid domain object. The domain object it's returning is too generic. To counter this you could split your aggregate method into two methods; one that returns Child and another that returns Composite. Your application service then decides which one to call (if possible).

If for some reason you need your aggregate to return a generic object, I'd reconsider the design you have chosen.

Another "hack" is to simply put a property on your domain object that indicates whether it's a composite or child. I assume the aggregate will know if it is and be able to populate that property accurately.

Comment: AFAIK there is "Design for uniformity" vs "Design for type safety" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). You are talking about 2nd one, while my implementation is 1st one. The only time I need to differentiate between Composite and Child is when doing serialization/deserialization - but I guess it has to be that way.

Comment: The "Domain Driven Design" tag is throwing me off here. There are some instances where DDD is not needed and this might be one of them. When you do DDD, you design for the "SME" not specifically for type safety (even though that might ultimately be the result).
Having said that, what I have done in the past is have the parent and leaves implement an INode interface and that interface has a type property that contains what you are looking for.